# MYSQLi/PHP allowing duplicate entry on UNIQUE?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having a very strange problem.

This is what i have, in my structure the "email" field is clearly set to unique. However when i try to register with a duplicate email, instead of giving me a fat error it lets it slide. My database is having two rows with the same email..
The problem isnt just for email, even though i have them all set to unique it allows any and every field to have duplicates.. 
Any suggestions as to why this may happen? The field is not set to allow null.

Comment: check if there are leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: can you also post the result of this statement: `DESC yourTableName`

Comment: There are none, they are absolutely identical.

Comment: maybe you have set it as compound unique keys. i need to see the structure of your table.

Comment: Uploading screenshot of what PhpMyAdmin returned on DESC users.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/w6tCDJn.png

Comment: i can't see any key on the field `email`.

Comment: try adding `CONSTRAINT email_uq UNIQUE (Email)` in your DDL Statement

Comment: The problem is at all fields. As as i can tell the key is for the index and primary fields and is probably for indexing. I chose not to index email but make it primary when making my table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current table structure is

[image]

I can't see any `unique` key  defined in the table that's why it is possible to have duplicate email, try this:

```
CREATE TABLE UserList
(
    ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    igname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    verified VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT email_uq UNIQUE (email)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

> MYSQLi/PHP allowing duplicate entry on UNIQUE?

Nope.
It is some mistake with your code or data.

Comment: Well yeah.. But i need to know what the mistake is.

Comment: This is what debugging is for. And, if you're curious, we have no crystal ball to tell you what is the error in your code.

Comment: I understand that.. I am just hoping someone can tell me how to debug this D: